# AngularJs scroll-bars directive in select tag

Tags: angularjs

## AngularJs scroll-bars directive in select tag

can we use `ng-scrollbars` directive in `select` tag which has `ng-repeat`?

```
<select class="input" ng-model="x.model" scroll-bar scroll-config="x.config"
    ng-options="y as y.name for y in x.students">
</select>
```

Comment: after 20 days, it looks the answer is No ...